# "Size property has an invalid size of 0."

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am using this function:

```
Private Sub Trigger_sales(HIden As Guid)
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim Command As New SqlCommand()
        Command.Connection = connection
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Command.CommandText = "[WebSite].[ValidateWebTran]"
        Command.Parameters.Add("@UidWenTranGUID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)
        Command.Parameters("@UidWenTranGUID").Value = HIden
        Command.Parameters.Add("@sResultDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        Command.Parameters("@sResultDesc").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        Command.ExecuteScalar()
        If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error_process.text = Command.Parameters("@sResultDesc").Value.ToString)) Then
            complete_sales(HIden)
        End If
    End Sub
```

which results in this error:

> String[1]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be specifying a length for your `varchar` parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@sResultDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)
```

(Replace `255` with whatever parameter type `@sResultDesc` is. If it is `MAX` use `-1`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's this line:

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@sResultDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar)
```

you're not actually setting the value of the Param there , it should look like

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@sResultDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 'myValue
```

Like I said  , this is a guess from what part of your stored procedure is throwing exception

Comment: from where it is throwing i dont know but all the procedure in the database working well except this